# why does remote wp-admin redirect to localhost?

Tags: wordpress

I created a wordpress site on my local computer, then uploaded it to a remote server. The CSS wasn't working and I realised that it was looking at localhost to try to find it, when it should have been looking at the remote server. So I went to www.remoteserver.co.uk/wp-admin and it redirected me to localhost/wp-admin.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing the WordPress site URL is set to localhost. Update all localhost references in the **wp\_options** table in the database used on your remote server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've solved it now - it was a site url problem. I found this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: But `wp-admin` page notice: `ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.` although I don't disable cookie.

Comment: Thank you!  Defining WP-HOME and WP-SITEURL inside wp-login.php instantly fixed the issue.

Answer (score 7):

You need to change it in wp_options table in database, and after it, regen all perma links :)

Answer (score 6):

Go to phpmyadmin and follow the picture bellow:
[image]

Comment: as a database guy, this was the easiest one for me. note: if your site option in hosting is set to not include the www like (yoursite.com) and not (www.yoursite.com) make sure to enter with or without the (www) here as well, or your page will give you a "too many redirects" error.

Answer (score 1):

There are two areas in the WP_OPTIONS that you need to change. One is one the fisrt page and the other one is on the 2nd page.

This video will definitely help if you have access to phpMyAdmin

http://educhalk.org/blog/?p=21

Comment: I upload from localhost to server. It works, at least with my version: 4.4.2

Answer (score 0):

If your multisite site is set up on localhost then you need to do the following steps:

**for windows machine:**

**step1:** create the virtual host

Go to `xampp\apache\conf\extra` directory and find `httpd-vhosts.conf` file. Open it and put this code:

**For the first domain:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName multisite-one.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\multisite
    <Directory  "C:\xampp\htdocs\multisite">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**For the second domain:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName multisite-two.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\multisite
    <Directory  "C:\xampp\htdocs\multisite">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Go to the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` directory and find `hosts` file and open it as `administrator`. put these lines in it and restart the server.

```
#wordpress multisite set up
127.0.0.1   multisite-one.com
127.0.0.1   www.multisite-one.com

127.0.0.1   multisite-two.com
127.0.0.1   www.multisite-two.com
```

**step2:** Make changes in `wp-config.php` file as:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'multisite-one.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

**step3:** Make changes in the database as:

1. change domain and path in `wp_blogs` table.
2. change `siteurl` and `home` in `wp_options` table.

**Note:** In multisite WordPress creates the version of the table for `wp_options` as `wp_options` and `wp_2_options` etc. You need to change as per your requirement.